# Populate a HTML form with Zend Framework session

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I'm trying to populate a HTML form with data saved in session. This is what i've done so far but it's not working:

In my controller:

```
      $sessionErrorForm = new Zend_Session_Namespace('errorForm');

      $sessionErrorForm->prenom     = $form['prenom'];

      $this->_redirect('/inscription');
```

In my view, i need to display something in the value field if a session exists:

```
 <div><input type="text" name="prenom" value="<?php if (isset($sessionErrorForm->prenom)): echo $sessionErrorForm->prenom; endif;?>" title="Pr&#233;nom *"/>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: are you getting $form['prenom'] value before assign into session ?

Comment: yes this part is working. I tested the data in session, it's correct...It just does not display in the HTML

Comment: does you are getting data without isset condition ?

Comment: It's not working either without the isset unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Same thing like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562128/accessibility-of-a-session-in-a-view/12562662#comment16922516_12562662). You always have to instantiate your Session before you can access it. You can declare it in your controller:

```
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('errorForm');
$this->view->sessionErrorForm = $session;
```

And access it in your view with `$this->sessionErrorForm`:

```
<div><input type="text" name="prenom" value="<?php if (isset($this->sessionErrorForm->prenom)): echo $this->sessionErrorForm->prenom; endif;?>" title="Pr&#233;nom *"/>
```

Or you can declare it in your view and use it like the following:

```
<?php $sessionErrorForm = new Zend_Session_Namespace('errorForm'); ?>    
<div><input type="text" name="prenom" value="<?php if (isset($sessionErrorForm->prenom)): echo $sessionErrorForm->prenom; endif;?>" title="Pr&#233;nom *"/>
```

But nevertheless if you write into your session in a previous request you always have to create a new reference to your session, if you don't declare it in the scope before.