# Accessibility of a session in a view

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

I have created a Zend session in a view:

```
$user = Tools::getUserByLoginAndPassword($form);


if ($user instanceof Membre)
{
  $sessionUser = new Zend_Session_Namespace('user');
  $sessionUser->data = $user;


  $this->_redirect('/adresse');
}
```

I have tested $sessionUser->data, it contains the right data.
But i need to get this session in another view, and there, it's not working anymore...

for instance

```
<?php var_dump($sessionUser->data->prenom); ?>
```

displays "NULL" 
it worked fine in the previous view but not in this one.

I have placed my `Zend_Session::start();`
in the init() function of my controller...

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your session in another view, you have to instantiate it again. So if you use the following code you should be able to access your data:

```
<?php 
    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('user');
    Zend_Debug::dump($session->data);
?>
```

Comment: Could you have a look on my other question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561337/populate-a-html-form-with-zend-framework-session
you would be probably of some help for me !